Can the circles fit inside the triangle?
The diagram shows an equilateral triangle, a green semicircle and two congruent red circles. Wherever things look tangent, they are tangent.

Can two more red circles fit inside the triangle (with no overlapping)?

Picture:

 

Explanation:
First, observe that two red circles, having the same size and touching from the outside a third circle and a disjoint line and each other must be symmetrical around the perpendicular from the third circle's centre to the line (dashed blue line in the middle panel).
Mirroring the base of the given triangle across this axis (dashed blue line) yields a line parallel to the left side of the given triangle at the green circle's radius distance (cyan line in middle panel).
Rotate the cyan line and the red circles counterclockwise 120° around the centre of the given triangle (last panel). The image of the cyan line guarantees that the image of the two red circles is fully above the green circle.

@Pranay the dashed blue is perpendicular to the right side of the given triangle.

Ah yes sorry! Got it. This is awesome

Awesome construction. I believe there is a hidden assumption that the cyan line is parallel to the left side of the given triangle. Could you please elaborate on why that may be the case?

@BenjaminWang Not exactly hidden. It is clearly stated in the second paragraph. Note that the angle it forms with the right side of the triangle is the mirror image of the bottom right corner of the given triangle.

I am confused by something.  Regarding the horizontal line in the last panel, how do we know if it is above the green semicircle, tangent to the green semicircle or cuts the green semicircle?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson It is tangent. We know that because its preimage (w.r.t. 120° rotation) by construction passes through the centre of the green circle and therefore has distance one green-circle-radius from the left side of the triangle (which is the preimage of the base).

Self-answering. Here is the solution I had in mind.
The answer is:

Yes, two more red circles can fit.

Diagram:

 

Explanation:

First, notice that the original red circles are tangent to the sides of a smaller equilateral triangle, as shown. Now draw a horizontal line through the top of the green semicircle. Find the point where this line meets the right side of the triangle, and draw a circle centred at this point, tangent to the bottom side of the triangle. Notice that this new circle has the same radius as the green semicircle. Then we can certainly fit two new red circles above the horizontal line, tangent to the left side of the triangle as shown, by symmetry with the original diagram. Note that the bottom new red circle is tangent to the horizontal line; it is not clear whether it touches the horizontal line at the same point where the green semicircle touches the horizontal line, but that is not our concern (but I ask about that here). This is essentially the same as @Albert.Lang's solution, but instead of rotating, I added a circle with the same radius as the semicircle.



 Label the circles as below and set up coordinates such that the origin is the semicircle centre and the red circles have radius 1. Circle 3 is constructed to touch the outer triangle's two sloping sides; circle 4 is constructed to touch circle 3 and the outer triangle's left sloping side – we are to find out whether or not it overlaps the semicircle.

 The three shaded triangles are congruent with a smallest angle of 15°, so the semicircle's radius is $x=\csc\pi/12-1=2.863703\dots$ The outer equilateral triangle therefore has side length
 $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}+\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}+\sqrt3=8.770821\dots=[9,-72,-72,96,16]_3$$
 where the last notation means this number can be obtained as polyroots([9,-72,-72,96,16])[3] in mpmath. The vector from circle 1's centre to circle 3's has bearing 120° counterclockwise from the +x-axis and length this number minus $2\sqrt3$ or
 $$s=[9,-72,0,960,-1472]_3=5.306719\dots$$
 The coordinates of circle 1's centre are $(\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1},1)$. We now add the aforementioned vector $(-s/2,s\sqrt3/2)$ and then the vector from circle 3's centre to circle 4's, $(-1,-\sqrt3)$:
 $$z=([9,0,-144,-192,16]_2,\sqrt2+\sqrt6)=(0.0786909\dots,3.863703\dots)$$
 The gap between circle 4 and the semicircle is thus
 $$|z|-x-1=\mathbf{+0.000801254\dots}$$
 So two more red circles will fit… with tolerance even smaller than my 23 sprinklers problem!


Great, you have found the answer. But there is a solution that requires no calculation.

@Dan Do I look like I even care about elegance?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson The fact that the final gap is so small strongly suggests that a no-calculation solution has to be merely "draw everything extremely accurately (e.g. in GeoGebra) and conclude". This would be even less enlightening than my calculations.

@ParclyTaxel I assure you, there is an extremely elegant solution. A computer is not needed. Just a very simple diagram, then the result is obvious. I will post it later, if no one else does.

Yea, usually what people mean by "no-calculation proof" is "Euclidean proof", as in, as opposed to analytic proof. People doing analytical proof is always impressive tho, needs extra focus for all the numbers.

The other two answers suggest there is zero gap, but you have found a small nonzero gap. What gives? Thanks.

@BenjaminWang That most likely means the other answers are flawed. By the way I did draw everything out in GeoGebra and I did see the gap.

@BenjaminWang The other answers show that, after we add two new red circles, there is zero gap between the lower new red circle and the horizontal line through the top of the green semicircle. There is a small gap between the lower new red circle and the green semicircle, because their centres do not lie on the same verical line.

@Dan thank you for the explanation. That's pretty interesting. Then I wonder how far is the line "0-4" from vertical? (Must be a very small angle)

@BenjaminWang The final coordinates of 4's centre are given, you can work it out yourself.

About 1.2 degrees!
